# How to write to file in java by windows-1256 encoding

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am trying in JAVA 8, for  "windows-1256" file Writing 
my last try was :

```
  String win1256="...";
```

//

```
  File file = new File ("C:\file1.txt");
  OutputStreamWriter   os = new OutputStreamWriter (new 
  FileOutputStream(file),"windows-1256");
  os.write(win1256);
```

or :

```
  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\file1.txt");
  out.write(win1256.getBytes("windows-1256"));
```

however didn't work and output file was unreadable with "???..."

Comment: did you try upper-case "Windows-1256"?

Comment: Well ... With adding a `os.close()`, I get the expected output (in the file). Voted to close as unclear. Please provide a [mcve] if you still have problems.

Comment: I think the former will work fine.  Do you have an editor which can handle Windows-1256 encoding correctly?

Comment: @saka1029 i select in editor -after run prgram and write-  win1256 exactly

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose  in the real Code the term os.close exist.

Comment: @Datz i tried both of W and w

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changing is:

```
byte[] originalBytes; // Here the sequence of bytes representing the UTF-8 encoded string
Encoding enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");
byte[] newBytes = enc.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(originalBytes));
```

Comment: You asked about Java but `Encoding.GetEncoding` is C# (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencoding?view=netcore-3.1))! What code did you use to answer your question for Java?